# How to draw text letter by letter in glut?

Tags: c++, opengl, text, draw, glut

I can't get my GLUT program to work properly.I want to draw text (a char array) letter by letter with some miliseconds interval. My program:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <glut.h>
#include<iostream>

int hei = glutGet(GLUT_SCREEN_HEIGHT)/2;
int wid = glutGet(GLUT_SCREEN_WIDTH)/2;
void *font = GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24;
void *fonts[] =
{
  GLUT_BITMAP_9_BY_15,
  GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_10,
  GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24
};

void selectFont(int newfont)
{
  font = fonts[newfont];
  glutPostRedisplay();
}

void selectColor(float r, float g, float b)
{
glColor3f(r, g, b);
  glutPostRedisplay();
}




char *msg;

void tick(void)
{
  glutPostRedisplay();
}
void timer(int value) {

}
int element=0;
void output(int x, int y, char *string, bool center=true) {
  int len;
  len = strlen(string);
  if(center){
  glRasterPos2f((wid-len), y);
  }
  else {
  glRasterPos2f(x, y); 
  }
 for(int i=0;i<len;i++) {
    glutBitmapCharacter(font, string[i]);
    glPopMatrix();
    glutSwapBuffers();
    Sleep(500);
 }
}
void outputmsg(int x, int y, bool center=true) {
  int len;
  len = strlen(msg);
  if(center){
  glRasterPos2f((wid-len), y);
  }
  else {
  glRasterPos2f(x, y); 
  }
 for(int i=0;i<len;i++) {
     glutBitmapCharacter(font, msg[i]);
 }
}
void updatemsg() {
    msg="test msg letter by letter";
}
void display(void)
{
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  msg="|";
  updatemsg();
  if(msg!="|")
    output(wid, hei, msg, true);
  else
    output(wid,hei,msg,true);
}
void reshape(int w, int h)
{
  glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glLoadIdentity();
  gluOrtho2D(0, w, h, 0);
  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}
void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y) {
    switch(key){
    case 27:
        exit(1);
        break;
    }
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int i, msg_submenu, color_submenu;

  glutInit(&argc, argv);
  for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    if (!strcmp(argv[i], "-mono")) {
      font = GLUT_BITMAP_9_BY_15;
    }
  }
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
  glutInitWindowSize(wid*2, hei*2);
  glutCreateWindow("CHAT");
  glutFullScreen();
  glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  glutDisplayFunc(display);
  glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
  glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
  glutIdleFunc(tick);
  selectFont(0);
  glutMainLoop();
  return 0;             /* ANSI C requires main to return int. */
}
```

It does really weird stuff like erasing the previus one char then printing then printing the next one and the erased one. I tried everything what i could find about this topic on the forums. How can i fix it?

Comment: we are not a "give me the codez!!!" site, show us what you can do and we can try to help further

Comment: [google opengl text tutorial](https://www.google.at/#q=opengl+text+tutorial). Show us some research effort on what you have already done, finding tutorials is not a SO job.

Comment: I edited the code with the entire program code.

Comment: You're abusing the display callback. It's there to ask you to draw one frame, not draw a multitude of frames blocking in the meanwhile.

Answer (score 2):

What you should do is also hold the length of the string you want to display and increment it every few milliseconds:

```
int len;
char *msg;

void incrementLength(int value){
   if(msg[len]==0)return; //end of string stop the callback
   len++;
   glutTimerFunc(100, incrementLength, 0);
   glutPostRedisplay();
}

void updatemsg() {
    msg="test msg letter by letter";
    len=0;
    glutTimerFunc(100, incrementLength, 0);
}
```

And then in outputmsg (if you actually call it) you only loop until len:

```
void outputmsg(int x, int y, bool center=true) {

  if(center){
  glRasterPos2f((wid-len), y);
  }
  else {
  glRasterPos2f(x, y); 
  }
 for(int i=0;i<len;i++) {
     glutBitmapCharacter(font, msg[i]);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### This code has a couple of issues:

```
 for(int i=0;i<len;i++) {
    glutBitmapCharacter(font, string[i]);
    glPopMatrix();
    glutSwapBuffers();
    Sleep(500);
 }
```

1. You are popping a matrix that you never pushed anywhere, and you are doing it `len`-many times.
2. You are swapping buffers without clearing the screen in-between... that's going to lead to undefined results (generally a garbled mess of characters from previous frames).

You really need to re-think how you've implemented this.

I would suggest you implement some elapsed time check in your `display (...)` function that determines which character to print, rather than doing this in a loop that calls `Sleep (...)`.

Comment: I'd make that more than a suggestion. The OP's approach is _not_ how to use the `glutDisplayFunc` callback.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Well, as you can see from ratchet freak's answer, there are multiple ways of approaching this. It could be done with a timer, or it could be done once-per frame. It is true that it cannot remain the way it is currently, however.